# typeorm mongo full text search - sort with $meta: "textScore"

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, typeorm

I'm using typeorm to connect on mongodb,
Is typeorm support sort on relevant score return from full text search mongodb?
Like described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#sorting).

from mongo, i want to make query as:

```
db.todos.find( {$text: { $search: "coffee" }}, {score: { "$meta": "textScore" }}) .sort({score: { "$meta": "textScore" }}) .limit(20);
```

How can i query from MongoRepository from typeorm?
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry i can't understand what you are trying to achieve. You want to sort the returned values by the *score* value? Explain in simple words what you want from TypeORM so we can help you :)

Comment: yes, i want to sort return values base on score with typeorm

Answer (score 2):

I've been working a full day to discover how to make this mongo query work the same way on typeorm. Here's the result of this:

On the schema file, you need to put on the field that you configure your index at `mongo @Index({ fulltext: true })` like this (in my case I use the field Title):

```js
 @Index({ fulltext: true })
 @Column()
  title: string;
```

Inside the order option from method find, you add `['score']: { $meta: "textScore" }`, the score its the field that mongo generate when you`re trying to search by index.
If you need, you can add others kind of filters too inside the order.
And the function find will be like this:

```js
const announcements = await this.ormRepository.find({
      where: {
        $text: { $search: 'search query here' }
      },
      //@ts-ignore
      order: { ['boosted']: 'DESC', ['score']: { $meta: "textScore" } },
      select: ['id', 'title', 'images', 'address', 'categories'],
      take: 50,
    });
```

I add the //@ts-ignore because I wasn`t able to type this field because it doesn`t exist until the search has been done on mongo, so I just ignore, because the order expect the types 1, -1, undefined, 'ASC' and 'DESC', but it's working very well this way, ordering by score.

Comment: Jo I go the same issue, but this doesn't work for me, I can only do exact searches and not partial searches, lets say my indexed field value is "string", I can't find it if I jsut search for "str". So ultimately I don't seem to get a score

Comment: Try create a index by command line with the integrated mongo terminal, this terminal it's usually on the bottom of the MongoCompass, I have some problems creating the index by the Compass interface, so I use the terminal and works fine

Comment: Here the example how to create by terminal: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-compass-comes-with-shell

Comment: Another question: what is the boosted for? I tried this and realized that removing score" {meta... still works. but whats the logic for the boosted?

Comment: The "boosted" it`s  a property that I was using to filter on my search, on my case above I order my results by "boosted" value, you could use any other property on your document, like order by created_at for example...

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the following code and it works:

```
await todoRepository.find({
  where: {
    $text: { $search: 'search query here' },
  },
  take: 20
});
```

**P.S. You need to ensure you have a text index on a field in the Todo collection.**

I'm not sure if sorting by `score` is working properly with TypeORM. I haven't got any success so far.

Comment: Jo I go the same issue, but this doesn't work for me, I can only do exact searches and not partial searches, lets say my indexed field value is "string", I can't find it if I jsut search for "str". So ultimately I don't seem to get a score