# TypeOrm, MongoDB fulltext Search with score

Tags: mongodb, search, nestjs, full-text-search, typeorm

The Code:

```
repository.find({
  where: { $text: { $search: 'strin' }, score: { $meta: 'textScore' } },
  take: 10,
});
```

Gives me the Error: `MongoError: unknown operator: $meta`

According to Other Stackoverflows, you would have to write something like this:

```
repository.find(
  { $text : { $search : "text to look for" } }, 
  { score : { $meta: "textScore" } }
)
```

But that does not work since find only accepts a where and not 2 arguments.

Here the types:

- `find(options?: MongoFindManyOptions<Entity>): Promise<Entity[]>;`
- FindMany extends FindOne by skip and take
- `where?: ObjectLiteral;`

So yea, basically I have got nothing to work with and nothing I try works.
If I go and make where an array it complains about it not being an Object so I kinda can't replicate what the other stackoverflows suggest

Comment: If your goal is to return the score, I don't believe this is possible (because typeORM uses `select: [key1, key2, key3]`). If you just need to sort by the score, this answer would suggest you can do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655423/typeorm-mongo-full-text-search-sort-with-meta-textscore

Comment: That's the question I come from which does not work.
If I do that, and search for "strin" and sort by score I get nothing, wheras if I search by "string" I get the document with name value "string"    
Thats why I am wondering how to enable the score, it seems to not create it

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/e49d0c8740b9dec45448131edc012a920e6fcea2/src/entity-manager/MongoEntityManager.ts#L1038 says:

```
// todo: implement
```

If I get it, the problem is there is no where to map the text score to. The projection part of `options?: MongoFindManyOptions` allows you to choose which properties of the model to populate with data, but that's all:

```
        return selects.reduce((projectCriteria, key) => {
            projectCriteria[key] = 1
            return projectCriteria
        }, {} as any)
```

`1` is hardcoded, so there is no way to project new field `score` with calculated value `{ $meta: "textScore" }`